# absolute positioning to make a div extend the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, absolute

See image for my problem, any input would be greatly appreciated!

Image LINK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgSqC.png

Here's a fiddle with a template if it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/JUnTn/

HTML:

```
<div id="map-header">
TOP HEADER
</div><!-- end map-header -->


<div id="map-column">
LEFT COLUMN
</div><!-- end map-column -->


<div id="map-container">
    FILLS THE REST OF THE PAGE
</div><!-- end map-container -->
```

CSS

```
html{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        body {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        #map-header{
            clear:both;
            width:100%;
            height:100px;
            border-bottom:2px dotted gray;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #map-column{
            width:100px;
            float:left;
            background-color:green;
            border-right:2px dotted gray;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #map-container{
            float:left;

            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

EDIT:
still looking for assistance on this, I got this so far based off some research I did around Stack:
http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1152/

Still isn't exactly what I need, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I put my code in the fiddle, it wouldn't let me post the link without "accompanying" code

Comment: Please paste the code here and all other pertinent parts. Show some effort.

Comment: Alright I did so. sorry new to all this

Comment: Hi, Why not you use this `$("#map-container").css("width", screen.width);` thats what I used. Its perfect! And also, keep using `position: absolute`

Comment: Also, its jQuery! So use it in script.

Comment: Ok thanks Afzaal,

I have gotten to this without using any Jquery, just straight CSS. Is there a way to make the height of both bottom divs fit the entire page?

http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1152/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want,see the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JUnTn/2/

I wrapped the two div's inside another div.

```
#test{
width:100%;
}
#map-column{
width:10%;
float:left;         
}
#map-container{
float:left;
width:90%;
}
```

Comment: I originally attempted this, but I decided that I wanted the left and top bar to be fixed at 100px instead of 10%

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="map-column">
    LEFT COLUMN
</div><!-- end map-column -->
<div id="map-container">
    FILLS THE REST OF THE PAGE
</div><!-- end map-container -->
<br class="clear" />
```

CSS

```
br.clear{
    clear: both;
}
#map-column{
    float: left;
    width:100px;
}
#map-container{
    float: right;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myWidth = $(window).width() - 100;
    $('#map-container').css('width',myWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cool top bottom left right  trick to get this (got from pinterest). When I normally want a full screen, edge to edge, I use,

```
.full_container{ top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 }
```

In your scenario, since you want the 100px top and left padding you can do,

```
.full_container{ top: 100px, left: 100px, right: 0, bottom: 0 }
```

- Note, this is assuming you are using absolute positioning.